# bash: spec: command not found

Tags: ruby, rspec

I installed `rspec` gem. I got following message

```
Successfully installed rspec-2.11.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rspec-2.11.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for rspec-2.11.0...
```

but when I run

```
  spec path/to/file.rb
```

I get

```
-bash: spec: command not found
```

Any solution on this?

Comment: What is the output of `which spec`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should run

```
rspec path/to/file.rb
```

Comment: Indeed. The command is now `rspec` and not `spec`. It's been this way for almost two years now.

Answer (score 1):

First try to use `rspec` instead of just `spec`

Secondly, try this
    export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/gems/bin

obviously replace the dummy path with the correct one, pointing to the bin dir inside your gem instalation path. For example, mine is `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin`